# Generate Joined Lists of Given Size in python

Tags: python, set, combinations

I've been searching around, but I'm not quite sure how to word this. I have a list of lists, and each inner list is a certain size, k. I want to generate a list of combinations that have the size k+1. So for instance, if I start with:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[3,4]]
```

I want to generate the list:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,4]]
```

Where the lists are arbitrarily long. I'm thinking I'll need to use the combinations function from the itertools library, and possibly sets with unions. I'm just kind of stuck as to how to go about this efficiently.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I need to clarify. I'm only trying to generate the lists of length k+1 (3 in this case) where two of the original lists are combined. So if they were sets, I want only the resulting sets of length k+1 when we take the union of two sets.

Comment: what happened to the combinations `(1,2,4)` and `(2,3,4)`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make this very clear. So I want to generate only lists that can be made up of two lists. So (1,2) and (1,3) together make (1,2,3). And (1,3) and (3,4) make (1,3,4). So if they were sets, only the union of two sets that have length of 3. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what about something like this?

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lol = [[1,2],[1,3],[3,4]]
>>> k = len(lol[0])
>>> pair_sets = (set().union(*x) for x in combinations(lol,2))
>>> keep = [sorted(x) for x in pair_sets if len(x) == k+1]
>>> keep
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4]]
```

---

`set().union(*x)` is just a nice way to get the union of an arbitrary collection of sets; here we could equally well have used `set(x[0]).union(x[1])` instead.

The elements yielded by `pair_sets` are sets which look like

```
>>> pair_sets = list(set().union(*x) for x in combinations(lol,2))
[set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3, 4]), set([1, 3, 4])]
```

and then we keep the ones with length `k+1`, sorting them for good measure.

Comment: This only works if the lists are individually sorted to start with.

Comment: Perfect. That set().union(*x) is what was eluding me. I didn't consider using the splat! Thank you so much!

Comment: @roippi: could you explain?

Comment: @DSM like, if the input was `[[3,2],[1,3],[7,2]]`, your sort operation jumbles up the output order.

Comment: @roippi: as I understand it, we're only interested in the collections as sets, in which case the order doesn't matter.  I sorted them for display purposes only.  Could be mistaken, of course.

Comment: @DSM fair, if order doesn't matter this is fine.  I'll add an answer that preserves order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure about your expected output, because it's missing a few combinations, but try this:

```
import itertools
L = [[1,2],[1,3],[3,4]]
print list(itertools.combinations(list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(L))), len(L[0])+1))
```

`list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(L)))` will flatten the list and get the unique elements. Then we get the combinations of it with the length of the first item (`k`)

Comment: I'm not trying to generate all combinations, just the combinations of length k+1 when two of the lists are merged. I'm sorry, I think I've worded the original question terribly. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the order of your outputs, @DSM's answer is the correct one.  However, if you have inputs like `[[3,2],[1,3],[7,2]]` and you need to preserve the order of the input, you need to be more sophisticated, since order is obliterated the second your elements enter a `set`.

I'll mirror his code so you can see the difference:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
from collections import OrderedDict
lol = [[3,2],[1,3],[7,2]]
k = len(lol[0])
pair_sets = [list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(x))) for x in combinations(li,2)]
keep = [x for x in pair_sets if len(x) == k+1]
keep
[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks. At this point, I'm not sure if the algorithm requires stability or not. I appreciate you taking the time to do this though, I very well might need this!

Comment: `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(source))` is my favourite way to fake an `OrderedSet`.  Still wish they would have given us a real one.

Comment: @DSM yeah, I agree.  I'm not one to care about performance, but c'mon, how much more intuitive would it be to just have a proper `OrderedSet`.  Ah well.